# How to Set up POM Structure using selenium java and (TestNG Framework)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, software-quality

I'm new for QA automation and I have average knowledge in java,
so I decided to use (Selenium+Java) to do automation.
I will attach the code I did to the automation.and the script runs smoothly.
But the Structure I did is incorrect as I want to follow the (POM-Selenium).POM-Page Oriented Model

This Script navigates as Follows

Login(Page)-->Peronal(Drop/down Selection)--->AddEdit((Drop/down Selection))-->Personal(Page)-->Add(Button)-->PersonalDetails(Page)

The test scenario is......

the user should "login" to the system,  and have to click "personal" drop down in the navigation tab then there will be an "AddEdit" drop downselection.then the user is directed to the page titled as "personal", the user should click "Add" button on that page to get directed to another page called "personal Details" user can add the relevant fields which are provided from the page to add a new Client.

Please help me to arrange this to POM Structure.because I'm having very hard time to think how it goes.what frustrates me is in order user to add a relevant record he/she should be logged in to the system and in POM it says login is a separate page I have to navigate through three pages to complete the task.it would be great if you can help me out.and it's open to discussion and sorry if my English is bad. and please consider me as a total noob when it comes to automation :) thanks!

This is the Test Script I wrote...

```
package TestNG;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//public String baseUrl;
//public  String driverPath;
//public WebDriver driver;

public class Tester {
    public String baseUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxx/";
    public String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe";
    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void Login() {

        System.out.println("launching firefox browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        WebElement username = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"userId\"]")));
        username.sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
        WebElement password = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginPassword\"]")));
        password.sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/button")));
        button.click();
        String expectedTitle = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String actualTitle = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/h1")))
                .getText().toString();
        // System.out.println(actualTitle);
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);

        // driver.close();

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void Personal_Tab_Selection() {

        clickWhenReady("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a", 10, driver);

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void Add_Edit_Selection() {

        clickLinkByHref("/rsa/5/15/staff/n/i/list", driver);

    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void Add_Button() {
        clickWhenReady("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/a", 10, driver);

    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void Radio_Button_AMW() {
        WebElement amw_radio = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label[1]")));
        amw_radio.click();
    }

    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void Radio_Button_service_provider() {
        WebElement service_provider = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/label[1]")));
        service_provider.click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 6)
    public void Service_Provider_Name_select() {

        WebElement Service_Provider_DD = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                        By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/a")));
        Service_Provider_DD.click();

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(2)")).click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 7)
    public void Employee_Code_Enter() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/input"))
                .sendKeys("01112");

    }

    @Test(priority = 8)
    public void Click_Salutation() {
        WebElement Salutation_DD = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/a")));
        Salutation_DD.click();
    }

    @Test(priority = 9)
    public void Salutation_Click() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/ul/li[5]"))
                .click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 10)
    public void employee_name() {

        WebElement empname = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[7]/div/input"));
        empname.sendKeys("Test2");
    }

    @Test(priority = 11)
    public void Sap_plant_code() {
        WebElement plant_code = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[8]/div/div/a")));
        plant_code.click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 12)
    public void sap_code_set() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[8]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]"))
                .click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 13)
    public void sap_vendor_code() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[9]/div/input"))
                .sendKeys("test_2");

    }

    @Test(priority = 14)
    public void employee_role_select() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/ul")).click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 15)
    public void select_Technician_role() {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/div/ul/li"))
                .click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 16)
    public void select_status() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[11]/div/div/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[11]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]"))
                .click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 17)
    public void click_save_button() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/button[1]")).click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 18)
    public void Record_add_notification_Check() {

        if ((new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/button"))) != null) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/button")).click();
        } else {
            infoBox("not Added", "Not Added");
        }

    }

    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "InfoBox: " + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static void clickWhenReady(String location, int timeout, WebDriver driver) {

        WebElement element = null;

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(location)));

        element.click();

    }

    public static void clickLinkByHref(String href, WebDriver driver) {

        List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        Iterator<WebElement> i = anchors.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            WebElement anchor = i.next();
            if (anchor.getAttribute("href").contains(href)) {
                anchor.click();

                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few words about your script:

1. `presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"userId\"]"))` - If an element have an `id` you should always try to use `id` instead of `xpath`
2. `By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/button"))` - It is recommended to use `logical xpath` instead of `absolute xpath` as much as possible. Else your `xpath` becomes vulnerable.
3. Now as you are willing to follow the POM, you need to define all the elements of a page in a single page which will be called the PageFactory. Likewise, all the Elements of a webpage will reside in separate class.

For e.g. an entry for an element on a webpage may look like:

```
@FindBy(id="user_login") 
WebElement username;
```

4. As you are using TestNG, you can move the Browser related code to a seperate class `Browserfactory`. From your test class, within `@BeforeTest` Annotation call the methods of `Browserfactory` to initialize the browser, open the url.

These are some of the basic steps to implement your code through POM.

Let me know if this solves your query.

Comment: Thank you, Dev I'm on it at the moment and I highly value your respond.ill upload the pom structured code when I'm done.and the answer is very helpful.Thank you!

Comment: @VaasPerera I am glad I am able to help you. Having said that I will say, there are more to POM which I will suggest you gradually for code reusibility & better performance. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, Dev! I'll upload my code as soon as i finish this :) for you to examine and give me a feedback.for me it's easy to code in a single file and run than following POM because i have to deal with more complex scenarios like method overloading and overriding, since now I'm refactoring my code POM structure when I'm reusing the code i have to think and design the methods that worked fine when it was in a one file and how it should work in POM.so bit frustrating to me... but i want guidance please ill upload as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

These are the classes I created depending on the pages of UI,ill attach the structure as a snapshot too :) [image: Structure of Eclipse]

```
public class Driver_class {

    private static String baseUrl;
    private static String driverPath;
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {

        baseUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx:xx\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe";

        if (driver == null) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(baseUrl);
        }
        return driver;

    }

}


public class Login {

    public WebElement uid;
    public WebElement pwd;
    public WebElement loginbtn;

    public void get_elements(WebDriver driver) {
        uid = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"userId\"]")));

        pwd = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginPassword\"]")));

        loginbtn = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/button")));

    }

    public void customerLogin() {

        this.uid.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
        this.pwd.sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxx");
        this.loginbtn.click();

    }

}

public class Navigation {

    public WebElement Personal_Tab;
    public WebElement Add_Edit_p;

    public void navigate_personal_button(WebDriver driver) {

        clickWhenReady("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a", 10, driver);

    }

    public void navigate_personal_add_button(WebDriver driver) {

        clickLinkByHref("/rsa/5/15/staff/n/i/list", driver);


    }

    public static void clickWhenReady(String location, int timeout, WebDriver driver) {

        WebElement element = null;

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(location)));

        element.click();

    }

    public void clickLinkByHref(String href, WebDriver driver) {

        List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        Iterator<WebElement> i = anchors.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            WebElement anchor = i.next();
            if (anchor.getAttribute("href").contains(href)) {
                anchor.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }




}
public class Personal_Details {

    WebElement amw_radio;
    WebElement service_provider;
    WebElement Service_Provider_DD;
    //WebElement Employee_Code_Enter;

    WebElement Click_Salutation;
    WebElement Salutation_DD;
    WebElement empname;
    WebElement plant_code;


    //WebElement

    public void Radio_Button_AMW(WebDriver driver) {
         amw_radio = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label[1]")));
        amw_radio.click();
    }


    public void Radio_Button_service_provider(WebDriver driver) {
        service_provider = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/label[1]")));
        service_provider.click();
    }


    public void Service_Provider_Name_select(WebDriver driver) {

        Service_Provider_DD = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                        By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/a")));
        Service_Provider_DD.click();

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(2)")).click();

    }


    public void Employee_Code_Enter(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/input"))
                .sendKeys("01112");

    }


    public void Click_Salutation(WebDriver driver) {
        Salutation_DD = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/a")));
        Salutation_DD.click();
    }


    public void Salutation_Click(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/ul/li[5]"))
                .click();

    }


    public void employee_name(WebDriver driver) {

         empname = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[7]/div/input"));
        empname.sendKeys("Test2");
    }


    public void Sap_plant_code(WebDriver driver) {
        plant_code = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[8]/div/div/a")));
        plant_code.click();

    }


    public void sap_code_set(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[8]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]"))
                .click();

    }


    public void sap_vendor_code(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[9]/div/input"))
                .sendKeys("test_2");

    }


    public void employee_role_select(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/ul")).click();

    }


    public void select_Technician_role(WebDriver driver) {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/div/ul/li"))
                .click();

    }


    public void select_status(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[11]/div/div/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[11]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]"))
                .click();

    }


    public void click_save_button(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/button[1]")).click();

    }


    public void Record_add_notification_Check(WebDriver driver) {

        if ((new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/button"))) != null) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/button")).click();
        } else {
            infoBox("not Added", "Not Added");
        }

    }

    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "InfoBox: " + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }


}


public class Personal_list {

    WebElement add_btn;


    public void find_add_btn(WebDriver driver) {

          String add_btn_path = "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/a";    
          detect_element_click(driver, add_btn_path);


    }

    public void detect_element_click(WebDriver webDriver, String xp) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xp))).click();

    }
}
```

This is the TestCaseClass Which executes all test_cases

```
public class TestCases {

    public WebDriver driver = Driver_class.getDriver();

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void newCustomerLogin() {

        Login rsaLogin = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login.class);
        rsaLogin.get_elements(driver);
        rsaLogin.customerLogin();

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void click_Personal_tab() {

        Navigation n = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Navigation.class);
        n.navigate_personal_button(driver);
        n.navigate_personal_add_button(driver);


    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void click_add_tab() {

        Personal_list ps= PageFactory.initElements(driver,Personal_list.class);
        ps.find_add_btn(driver);


    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void Enter_personal_details(){

        Personal_Details d= new Personal_Details();
        d.Radio_Button_AMW(driver);
        d.Radio_Button_service_provider(driver);
        d.Service_Provider_Name_select(driver);
        d.Employee_Code_Enter(driver);
        d.Click_Salutation(driver);
        d.Salutation_Click(driver);
        d.employee_name(driver);
        d.Sap_plant_code(driver);
        d.sap_code_set(driver);
        d.sap_vendor_code(driver);
        d.employee_role_select(driver);
        d.select_Technician_role(driver);
        d.select_status(driver);
        d.click_save_button(driver);
        d.Record_add_notification_Check(driver);






    }

}
```